# Pandas Random Weighted Choice

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I would like to randomly select a value in consideration of weightings using `Pandas`.

`df`:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  40  5 20 10 35 25
1  24  3 12  6 21 15
2  72  9 36 18 63 45
3  8   1  4  2  7 5
4  16  2  8  4 14 10
5  48  6 24 12 42 30
```

I am aware of using `np.random.choice`, e.g:

```
x = np.random.choice(
  ['0-0','0-1',etc.], 
  1,
  p=[0.4,0.24 etc.]
)
```

And so, I would like to get an output, in a similar style/alternative method to `np.random.choice` from `df`, but using `Pandas`. I would like to do so in a more efficient way in comparison to manually inserting the values as I have done above.

Using `np.random.choice` I am aware that all values must add up to `1`. I'm not sure as to how to go about solving this, nor randomly selecting a value based on weightings using `Pandas`.

When referring to an output, if the randomly selected weight was for example, 40, then the output would be 0-0 since it is located in that `column 0`, `row 0` and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stack the DataFrame:

```
stacked = df.stack()
```

Normalize the weights (so that they add up to 1):

```
weights = stacked / stacked.sum()
# As GeoMatt22 pointed out, this part is not necessary. See the other comment.
```

And then use sample:

```
stacked.sample(1, weights=weights)
Out: 
1  2    12
dtype: int64

# Or without normalization, stacked.sample(1, weights=stacked)
```

---

DataFrame.sample method allows you to either sample from rows or from columns. Consider this:

```
df.sample(1, weights=[0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.05, 0.05])
Out: 
    0  1   2  3   4   5
1  24  3  12  6  21  15
```

It selects one row (the first row with 40% chance, the second with 30% chance etc.)

This is also possible:

```
df.sample(1, weights=[0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.05, 0.05], axis=1)
Out: 
   1
0  5
1  3
2  9
3  1
4  2
5  6
```

Same process but 40% chance is associated with the first column and we are selecting from columns. However, your question seems to imply that you don't want to select rows or columns - you want to select the cells inside. Therefore, I changed the dimension from 2D to 1D.

```
df.stack()

Out: 
0  0    40
   1     5
   2    20
   3    10
   4    35
   5    25
1  0    24
   1     3
   2    12
   3     6
   4    21
   5    15
2  0    72
   1     9
   2    36
   3    18
   4    63
   5    45
3  0     8
   1     1
   2     4
   3     2
   4     7
   5     5
4  0    16
   1     2
   2     8
   3     4
   4    14
   5    10
5  0    48
   1     6
   2    24
   3    12
   4    42
   5    30
dtype: int64
```

So if I now sample from this, I will both sample a row and a column. For example:

```
df.stack().sample()
Out: 
1  0    24
dtype: int64
```

selects row 1 and column 0.

Comment: Awesome! Thank You. So this works in a similar style to `np.random.choice`? Also, What's the purpose of `stacking` in this case?

Comment: @LearningToPython Yes it does work exactly like random.choice. The purpose of stacking is to have a one-dimensional object (because pandas sample allows you to either sample from axis 0 or 1 (from rows or columns - not simultaneously as far as I know).

Comment: Okay. Great, Thanks. 1 last question (Sorry) - So why is stacking necessary in this case?

Comment: Unlike `np.random.choice`, weights do not need to be  normalized for `pd.DataFrame.sample` (just non-negative).

Comment: @LearningToPython I edited the post to explain that part.