# How to generate random categorical data in python according to a probability distribution?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, random

I am trying to generate a random column of categorical variable from an existing column to create some synthesized data. For example if my column has 3 values 0,1,2 with 0 appearing 50% of the time and 1 and 2 appearing 30 and 20% of the time I want my new random column to have similar (but not same) proportions as well

There is a similar question on cross validated that has been solved using R. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14158/how-to-generate-random-categorical-data. However I would like a Python Solution for this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas Random Weighted Choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45223537/pandas-random-weighted-choice)

Comment: Otherwise please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Perhaps this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55027404/generate-larger-synthetic-dataset-based-on-a-smaller-dataset-in-python

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [`np.random.choice()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) and specify a vector of probabilities corresponding to the chosen-from arrray:

```
>>> import numpy as np 
>>> np.random.seed(444) 
>>> data = np.random.choice(  
...     a=[0, 1, 2],  
...     size=50,  
...     p=[0.5, 0.3, 0.2]  
... )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
>>> data                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
array([2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1,
       1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2,
       1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1])
>>> np.bincount(data) / len(data)    # Proportions                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
array([0.44, 0.32, 0.24])
```

As your sample size increases, the empirical frequencies should converge towards your targets:

```
>>> a_lot_of_data = np.random.choice(  
...     a=[0, 1, 2],  
...     size=500_000,  
...     p=[0.5, 0.3, 0.2]  
... )
>>> np.bincount(a_lot_of_data) / len(a_lot_of_data)                                                                                                                                                                                                          
array([0.499716, 0.299602, 0.200682])
```

As noted by @WarrenWeckesser, if you already have the 1d NumPy array or Pandas Series, you can use that directly as the input without specifying `p`.  The default of `np.random.choice()` is to sample with replacement (`replace=True`), so by passing your original data, the resulting distribution should approximate that of the input.

Comment: If, instead of using `[0, 1, 2]` as the choices, you used the existing column, then you wouldn't need to specify `p`. The distribution of the random choices would naturally follow the distribution of the existing column.

Comment: That's a very good point.  I was assuming the probabilities specified should be exact, pinned at the percentages from the question.